# How to pass in &str when using rust asm! inline assembly

Tags: assembly, rust, inline-assembly

I want this function to operate the register with the specified name, but it seems that the asm! macro does not support it?

```
pub fn read_cpuid(reg: &str) -> u64 {
    let val: u64;
    unsafe {
        asm!("mrs {}, {}", 
            out(reg) val,
            reg
        );
    }
    val
}
```

The error message is as follows：

```
error: expected one of `clobber_abi`, `const`, `in`, `inlateout`, `inout`, `lateout`, `options`, `out`, or `sym`, found `r`
```

If I change r to pass it in using reg, it still doesn’t work.

```
use core::arch::asm;
pub fn read_cpuid(r: &str) -> u64 {
    let val: u64;
    unsafe {
        asm!("mrs {}, {}", 
            out(reg) val,
            in(reg) r
        );
    }
    val
}
```

```
error: cannot use value of type `*const str` for inline assembly
note: only integers, floats, SIMD vectors, pointers and function pointers can be used as arguments for inline assembly
```

I can only use enumeration to solve it now, but the scalability of this approach is too poor. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Explicit registers are string *literals*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/inline-assembly.html#register-operands) so they cannot come from a function parameter, a variable or even a constant but they must be typed directly when calling the `asm!` macro.

This makes sense since the compiler has to emit different binary code depending on the chosen register, and so must know the chosen register at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

`*const str` is a "fat" pointer, meaning it stores the length of the `str` alongside the pointer to the beginning of the `str`. Therefore, it can't fit within a single register.

Use [`str::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/primitive.str.html#method.as_ptr) so get a `*const u8` which is just a pointer.

```rust
use core::arch::asm;

pub fn read_cpuid(r: &str) -> u64 {
    let val: u64;
    unsafe {
        asm!("mrs {}, {}", 
            out(reg) val,
            in(reg) r.as_ptr()
        );
    }
    val
}
```

This error message is not great. I recommend [opening an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues) suggesting that the diagnostic be improved.

Comment: I made the modifications as you said, but I still get an error when I use it like this: `let cpuid = read_cpuid("midr_el1");`  The error message is: `error: expected readable system register; note: instantiated into assembly here: mrs x8, x9` It seems that the asm macro cannot directly embed the string into the assembly statement, and the expected result will not be achieved by passing in the register.

Comment: @SiminXiong I recommend opening a new question for that, explaining what you're trying to do, what architecture you're using, etc